# Converting a void pointer to an unsigned long

Tags: c, void-pointers

I am working on a C program that takes in a void pointer that I know for a fact points to an integer but I cant figure out how to correctly cast it to such. For example, the following will produce a C6011 warning.

```
int convert(PVOID val) 
{
   int value = *((int *) val); 
   return value;
}
```

However, I plan to use this in my kernel driver so warnings will be a problem and I really need to cast the PVOID into a ULONGLONG so that I can compare it to another ULONGLONG but I am not sure how to do that. When I print the value of the void pointer it prints the value as a ULONGLONG but its in hex when I need it in decimal in order to make comparing and printing the value easier.

Anyways the following code will produce a C222 error and a C4047 warning because it does not like me casting a void pointer to a ULONGLONG but I am not sure how to do this without generating any warnings, errors, or BSOD's.

```
bool same(PVOID val, ULONGLONG otherVal) 
{
   ULONGLONG value = val;
   return value == otherVal;
}
```

Comment: "it prints the value as a ULONGLONG but its in hex when I need it in decimal in order to make comparing and printing the value easier." How you print it is up to you. Hex and decimal are the same in memory..

Comment: I'm not familiar with the diagnostic codes of your compiler which you didn't name; you should just show us the full output of the compiler so we can see the warning ourselves.  The first code block you posted looks fine.

Comment: Why must it be `ULONGLONG`? Wouldn't `uintptr_t` be a more natural choice?

Comment: @DavidGrayson Well it might not be fine if the ULONGLONG is passed as an address or just cast to void* and passed as a value. In the latter case, you wouldn't dereferences.

Comment: @TedLyngmo This appears to be a Microsoft compiler.  Don't expect C standard compliance.

Comment: @AndrewHenle uint64_t should work fine then.

Comment: @AndrewHenle :-) I guess, but I've tried a few C programs in MSVC and it has the standard headers, like `stdint.h` etc. so `uintptr_t` should be in there and be the proper integer type for carrying pointer values.

Comment: Btw, `C6011` is a warning about dereferencing a null pointer so, that has nothing to do with your cast but rather that the compiler was able to notice that you will dereference a null pointer (which is not allowed).

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes it is a dereferencing a null ptr error but I am not sure how to fix it.  Also uintptr_t causes the same issues as ULONGLONG.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Well the ULONG or uintptr_t error says "warning C4047: 'initializing': 'uintptr_t' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'"

Comment: For pointer values, if you "need it in decimal in order to make comparing and printing the value easier" then it's time to step up to hexadecimal.

Comment: @Irelia Well you are supposed to print void pointers with %p which prints hex since printing with %d or %llu will cause a warning. All I am trying to do is convert a void pointer into the decimal form that can then be assigned to a variable.

Comment: @WeatherVane Then I would need to convert the ULONGLONG to hex and then compare it with == in the same function either way a conversion needs to be done.

Comment: Decimal and hexadecimal are human-readable formats, a textual representation of values. You cannot compare text with `==` in C. "So you can assign it to a variable". A numerical value is a value is a value (unless it is a phone or card "number").

Comment: @WeatherVane What are you saying you can certainly compare to integers with == in C I am not sure why you are trying to think of some abstract examples to explain something that was not asked. Setting an integer equal to 4 then you can check if it == 0x0004 and it will return true which is what I am trying to accomplish here. Even doing ``PVOID test = 0x0004`` then checking if test ==  4 will return true. But this does not answer how I can convert PVOID to an instance of another type like int or ULONGLONG.

Comment: Re “All I am trying to do is convert a void pointer into the decimal form”: Numbers do not have decimal forms or hexadecimal forms. Numbers are abstract mathematical entities. We represent them with strings of characters. A string of characters that represents a number is called a numeral. Numerals can be decimal or hexadecimal. However, this refers to, for example, the string of characters we print to convey the value of a number. When used in an expression, a number is not a numeral and is not decimal or hexadecimal. It is just a value…

Comment: I cannot understand why you think hexadecimal or decimal has anything to do with comparing pointers.

Comment: … To convert a `void *` to an integer type, you simply use a cast, as in `(uintptr_t) val`. The compiler should not complain about this. If it does, you should edit the question to provide a [mre], showing the actual code that produces the message.

Comment: Re “When I print the value of the void pointer it prints the value as a ULONGLONG but its in hex when I need it in decimal in order to make comparing and printing the value easier”: A significant problem here is you have just mentioned some code you have written and have not even described that code precisely, let alone showed an exact copy in a [mre]. If you print a `void *` using `%p`, then most C implementations will show the address as a hexadecimal numeral. This is merely formatting for display and does not mean the pointer is hexadecimal or decimal and has nothing to do with comparing.

Comment: Re “Yes it is a dereferencing a null ptr error but I am not sure how to fix it”: Your post states that, about the `void *`, “I know for a fact points to an integer”. It cannot both point to an integer and be a null pointer. A null pointer does not point to anything, so it cannot point to an integer. If it is a null pointer, do not dereference it. If you want to dereference a pointer, set the pointer to something other than a null pointer value. Also, if you mean a specific integer type, use that, like `int` or `unsigned long` or `uintptr_t`. Do not use “integer” to mean `int`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Doing that does in fact work thank you this is solved now.

Comment: Re “the following code will produce a C222 error and a C4047 warning because it does not like me casting a void pointer to a `ULONGLONG`”: That code does not contain a cast. In C, a cast is an explicit operator. It is a type name or description in parentheses used as an operator in an expression. For example, `ULONGLONG value = (ULONGLONG) val;` has a cast, and the compiler should not complain about it unless you have requested warnings related to width issues and there is such an issue. `ULONGLONG value = val;` does not have a cast…

Comment: … It has an implicit conversion, and the C standard requires warnings for implicit conversions from pointers to integer type, so a cast is required to avoid the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am working on a C program that takes in a void pointer that I know
> for a fact points to an integer but I cant figure out how to correctly
> cast it to such. For example, the following will produce a C6011
> warning.
>
> ```
> int convert(PVOID val) 
> {
>    int value = *((int *) val); 
>    return value;
> }
> ```

Based on the format of the error number, I guess you're compiling with MSVC.  [MSVC warning C6011](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6011?view=msvc-170) complains that you are dereferencing a pointer that may be null.  Apparently, then, MSVC is not as sure as you are that the pointer actually points to an integer.  Your cast & dereference is the correct way to get the `int` to which the pointer points.  It's only a warning, but you should be able to silence it by performing a null check before the dereference, something like this:

```
int convert(PVOID val) {
   if (val == NULL) {
      // abort or return a default value
   } else {
      return *((int *) val); 
   }
}
```

> However, I plan to use this in my kernel driver so warnings will be a problem and I really need to cast the PVOID into a ULONGLONG so that I can compare it to another ULONGLONG but I am not sure how to do that.

That sounds suspect, but if you intend to do it then you do exactly what you describe: *cast*, via a cast operator.  C explicitly allows such conversions.

> Anyways the following code will produce a C222 error and a C4047 warning because it does not like me casting a void pointer to a ULONGLONG but I am not sure how to do this without generating any warnings, errors, or BSOD's.

A [C4047](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4047?view=msvc-170) makes sense, but I have no idea what a C222 is.  I do not find it documented.  In any case, standard C permits you to convert pointers to integers, but such conversions are not implicit.  A cast is required:

```
bool same(PVOID val, ULONGLONG otherVal) {
   return otherVal == (ULONGLONG) val;
}
```

However, although that should clear the C4047, the code still has bad smell.  I don't know the circumstances that make such comparisons (seem) appropriate, but there is probably a cleaner approach.

Comment: But how can we be sure the value being passed into convert is actually passed as an address, and not a value simply cast to void*? The code you provided is correct but I don't think the question gave enough information.

Comment: @Irelia, the C language does not provide any mechanism by which the `convert()` function could determine with certainty whether its argument is in fact a valid pointer.  Verifying that it is not null is the best `convert()` can do, and sufficient to silence the 6011 warning. A non-null, invalid pointer is both more likely and potentially more problematic, which makes the C6011 warning somewhat pedantic.  But the question posed is about how to perform these actions correctly and what the warnings are trying to tell them, not about whether any of this is a good idea.